# Is my system("clear"); not clearing everything?

Tags: c, netbeans

I am currently doing my first school project and it involved a menu with multiple options.

What I decided to do was, every time an option from the menu was chosen, it would clear the screen and shows the most important things only.

Eg.

```
     do {

     printf("Menu\n");
     printf("1 - X\n");
     printf("2 - Y\n");
     printf("0 - Exit");
     scanf("%i",&op);

    switch(op)
    {
        case 1: { 
        system("clear");
        printf("Option chosen: 1\n\n");
        // The rest of the code inserting into arrays
        system("clear");
        printf("Option 1 results\n\n");
        // Results
        break; }

        case 2: {
        // Other code about listing, for example
        break; }
      }while(op != 0);
```

Now, the thing is:

On the first insert it all goes well, but for example, if i try to insert another one, the *printf("Option 1 results\n\n");* will appear on top and it will not be cleared. **So it will be something like:**

"Option 1 results"

"Option chosen: 1"

// Insert printfs in text

**It should be:**

"Option chosen: 1"

// Insert printfs in text

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This isn't very clear... is this code called from within a loop?

Comment: My bad. There is an "option != 0" do while in there for it to keep repeating untill he asks to quit.

Answer (score 0):

Command is "cls" not "clear"

try `system("cls");`

Better way of clearing screen (on Windows) will be to include `conio.h` and then call function `clrscr()`. It will clear the screen and place cursor at the start of terminal.

There are many functions in `conio.h` by which you can place cursor at certain location or change the colour of terminal

Comment: I do not think the MSVC `conio.h` does have any cursor positioning or colour functions (that was the old Borland one). But MSVC does have a set of [console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx), for example `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.

Comment: Conio.h got "gotoxy"

Comment: The old Borland one might, but not MSVC. No `clrscr` either.

Comment: I'm using cygwin so I would say it is "clear" as it is linux?
Now that I'm home and on my external screen, the error doesn't appear anymore, but when I change to the laptop screen it comes back.

Comment: In cygwin I'm not sure if `clear(1)` is implemented.  But you can use `printf("\033[2J");`  as this sends the ANSI escape sequence to erase the screen without having to call the shell to execute a new command.  It's less portable, but no less than using `system("clear");`.